# Why is schedule returning true 3 time instead of the values associated (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

```
/*facts 3.1*/
department(jack,cs).
department(sam,business).

subject(jack,computer_science). 
subject(jack,software_eng).
subject(sam,economics).
subject(sam,finance).

course(computer_science,CSE305). 
course(computer_science,CSE332).
course(software_eng,SE212). 
course(software_eng,SE102).
course(economics,ECO304). 
course(economics,ECO302).
course(finance,FIN102). 
course(finance,FIN103).

/*Rules 3.2 & 3.3*/
info(X,Y):-
   department(X,Y)
;  subject(X,Y).

schedule(X,Y):-
   subject(X,Z),
   course(Z,Y).
```

Why does the schedule function return true when passed (jack, X) for example. I am trying to get it to be all the courses that jack is taking

schedule(jack, X)

Goal:

```
X = CSE305; 
X = CSE332; 
X = SE212; 
X = SE102;`
```

Currently i get

```
true ? ;

true ? ;

true ? ;

yes
```

I am just at a complete loss

Comment: You should be seeing a whole lot of "singleton variable" warnings. Put your course names in single quotes to make them atoms, like this: `'CSE305'` and so on and see if this gets rid of the warnings. Then post the fixed code in your question and tell us what else is wrong.

Comment: Beginning with a capital letter means those are *variables* rather than course codes. Enclose them in single quotes, e.g. `'CSE305'`. Or, is simpler to just use lower-case. Use e.g. `bagof` to form a list - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3